CUBLAS root kernel is called twice for a reduction operation
I am making a call to the cublasSasum function only once from cuBLAS. I do see that the actual kernel it calls (asum_kernel) is called twice as seen from profiling via nsys. I am computing a sum for a total of 4096^2 elements.
 Time (%)  Total Time (ns)  Instances   Avg (ns)     Med (ns)    Min (ns)   Max (ns)   StdDev (ns)                              Name                             
 --------  ---------------  ---------  -----------  -----------  ---------  ---------  -----------  -------------------------------------------------------------
     17.9          415,655          2    207,827.5    207,827.5      3,264    412,391    289,296.5  void asum_kernel<int, float, float>(cublasAsumParams<T2, T3>)

Is the call made twice because the kernel performs block level reductions first, saves the result, and performs the final reduction on these temporary results?
PS : I tried the same with just 4 elements with 4 threads and only one grid block. Still the asum_kernel is called twice though one is sufficient in this case as there is only one block?!?

its quite typical that a reduction could be implemented as two (or more!) kernel calls.

Yes, I went through this pdf. So if I have to "measure" the total time taken by cuBLAS for this reduction operation, is it just the sum of 2 calls or something more to it?

I don't have implementation details on the CUBLAS library that I can share. But timing operations in CUDA has been discussed extensively on various forums, including here on the cuda SO tag.  For example, it seems quite possible to me to launch a CUDA "start" event before the cublas call, then launch a CUDA "stop" event after the CUBLAS call, and do timing measurement that way.  It should be good for many purposes I can think of.  It's going to capture the two kernel calls, plus the duration of time between those two.

If that's not what you want, for some reason, then you could use the profiler to add up the duration of the two kernel calls.  You could also use the profiler to inspect what is happening (if anything is visible) in between the kernel calls.  A CUBLAS call could even have preamble or postamble activity before or after those 2 kernel calls.  So you'll have to make some decisions about what is important to you, and study or reverse engineer a simple test case if necessary.  The exact sequence of operations is not described or specified by NVIDIA, and could change  CUDA version to version.

Totally appreciate the detail here. "Measure everything rather than simply measuring the kernel durations".

My recommendation would be Nsight Systems. You can tell it to specifically report cuBLAS calls as ranges in the timeline with --trace cublas.
